# Почему после сборки webpack`ом проекта с помощью babel получаю jsx файл вместо js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel, configuration

В папке билд получаю jsx файл который является тупо копией входного файла index.jsx. Создает 2 файла html, стили вообще не собрал и на конец в main.bundle.js ничего нету (Ошибок консоль не выдала, все нужные пакеты установлены ) В чём может быть причина ?

КОНСОЛЬ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итоговая папка build:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл конфигурации webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
 
module.exports = ( env, args ) => {
    const isProduction = args.mode === "production"

    const config = {
        entry: "./src/index.jsx",
        output: {
            filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
            publicPath: "/"
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /.(js?x)$/,
                    use: ["babel-loader"]
                },
                {
                    test: /.s?css$/,
                    use: [
                        isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
                        "css-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$/,
                    use: ["url-loader"]
                },
                {
                    test: /.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|)$/,
                    use: ["file-loader"]
                }
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html"
            })
        ],

        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
        }
    }

    if ( isProduction ) {
        config.plugins.push(
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                template: "[name].css"
            })
        )
    }

    return config
}
```

файл конфигурации .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": "> 1%",
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": 3
        }],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],

    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Команда сборки:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production"
```

Comment: поправил проверку скриптов, ничего не изменилось :)

Comment: {
                    test: /.(jsx?)$/,
                    use: ["babel-loader"]
                },